# PHP - Twitter api

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I had a small page that worked with the twitter api to get the last posts of some user and show them on a webpage, but since last week I doesn't work anymore.

It was using the old TwitterAPIExchange from James Mallison, and using the twitter api 1.1.

I tried changing to the Abraham\TwitterOAuth but I cannot make this work, I keep receiving the "client-not-enrolled" errors when I try to get users...

In the twitter developer part it seems that everything is ok, except maybe one thing... I am using the free option that seems to be very limited, may this be the reason? Or is it probable that I am doing something wrong?

Please help if you can.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token,            $access_token_secret, $bearer_token);
$connection->setApiVersion('2');
$response = $connection->get('users', ['ids' => ****]);
print_r($response);
```

result:

```
  stdClass Object
(
    [client_id] => ******
    [detail] => When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.
    [registration_url] => https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview
    [title] => Client Forbidden
    [required_enrollment] => Appropriate Level of API Access
    [reason] => client-not-enrolled
    [type] => https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The new owner of twitter have limited twitter free api access, and also deprecated some api v1.1 functions.